# Docker – Connection Refused

Tags: .net, docker

I am trying to learn how to use Docker.  I have installed Windows 10 on my PC at home and Docker for Windows works very well.

I am struggling trying to get Docker Toolbox working on my PC at work.  Here are the steps I have taken:

```
1) Launch Docker Toolbox
2) Run the following command inside Docker Toolbox: docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Here is the error:

[image]

I have spent hours investigating this.  So far I have tried:

1) Add the following lines to: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh

```
export http_proxy="http://MyUserName:MyPassword@myproxy:myport/"
export https_proxy="http://MyUserName:MyPassword@myproxy:myport/"
```

This made no difference.  Is there anything else I can do to debug this?

Could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: Have you tried with `--net=host` option when creating container?

Comment: Hi, have you try with other image pull like docker pull ubuntu:14.04 . it should work is there proxy or firewall configured?

Comment: @mulg0r, could you elaborate bearing in mind that I am relatively new to Docker? Thanks.

Comment: I have installed Docker on windows using this link.And its straight forward.   https://www.docker.com/docker-windows     Since you have windows 10 ....   you can try installing same,    As in this link https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/   Docker Toolbox is for Legacy desktop solution  ,....